# generate route url's in views or controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working with mvc4 and have a question around best practice.

I am passing back to my view, a number of links based on product information eg. product/1234 etc.

What is best practice, create the link using the routing engine in the controller and return the url as a property on the model object OR return the information to the view and generate the link there? I use `automapper` to map my DTO objects to model object, also considering creating the links during mapping.

What is the best practice with this?

Answer (score 0):

You always create the link on the view.

The HTML helpers in the view can be used to ensure the link conforms to your routing rules.

You can see this in action in the many [official ASP.NET MVC 4 Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4).

**Why not in the controller or model?**

The HTML helpers in the view are designed to create not just the URL, but also to wrap the URL in a fully formed anchor tag, etc. It isn't appropriate to have HTML in your model or controller as they shouldn't care how the data is displayed.

For example, the `Html.ActionLink` helper returns an `a` element.

Comment: So pass the model to the view that the url should be generated from? Why never in the controller?

Comment: I've added a bit of detail on that to the answer. I hope it helps to clarify.

Comment: One further question on this, I have tried to work with creating the URL on the view but as it is dependent on some logic - it is much easier to generate the URL in the controller. I am not generating the markup, just the URL. Does this break your rule?

Comment: @amateur - I wouldn't call it a rule - I would call it a principle. If you can't do what you need to do within that principle, you could deviate from it.